# Updating a row to be based on a transformation of another row (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, split, sql-update

I have a table with a few (~100) rows. One of the columns is basically a comma-separated list of strings that may or may not contain whitespace. Now I need another column that is a transformation of this column: Remove whitespace, separate by comma, sort alphabetically and concatenate again with comma.

I have the following SQL that works for one row (all other rows get the same value) but I can't figure out how to get it to work on the whole table. I'm probably missing a where but can't seem to get it right:

```
update client set sorted = (select listagg(somedata, ',') 
    within group (order by somedata) somedata from (
    with q as (select ','||regexp_replace(unsorted, '\s+', '') as somedata 
    from client)
select regexp_substr(somedata, ',([^,]+)',1,rownum,'i',1) somedata
from q,
(select 1 from q connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(somedata, '[^,]', '')))
));
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: That's a bad approach. Instead of having another column which stores essentially the same thing with sorted values is meaningless, when storing comma separated values itself is a bad practice in the first place. Rather, you must look at transforming them into another table by storing the individual values are rows, maybe with the same key from the parent table

Comment: I know that but when we initially developed the application, we had to treat it as a single String, the comma separation was meaningless to us. That changed now, though, but switching the whole structure isn't feasible.

Comment: As I always tell the OPs of such questions, It's  **now** or never. ..or the design is going to hurt  for ages to come.

Comment: While you're probably correct, I need the sorted Strings in one column as I do need to run a reasonably fast select based on the sorted column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client ( unsorted, sorted ) AS
  SELECT 'b , c  ,e f, d, a', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(30) ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z , y, x,w,v ,u', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(30) ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```sql
UPDATE client c
SET sorted = (
  SELECT LISTAGG(
           REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( c.unsorted, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ), '\s+' ),
           ','
         ) WITHIN GROUP (
           ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( c.unsorted, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ), '\s+' )
         )
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( c.unsorted, ',' ) + 1
)
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM client;
```

```
UNSORTED          | SORTED     
:---------------- | :----------
b , c  ,e f, d, a | a,b,c,d,ef 
z , y, x,w,v ,u   | u,v,w,x,y,z
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7834867a7ad25fbcbb8e99f9b46e3d44)*